# Still trying to get video to play in my app

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

Ok, so I failed to post my code properly last time ... I am the newbie. I altered things a bit and I am trying to get the video to play out of a uiTableView. I don't get a crash, I just get a black screen for about 20 seconds and then the simulator or iPhone returns to the uiTableView. When I select "option 1", I get the alert as expected. I am using Xcode 4.2 developing for iOS 4.0.

I have been searching and banging my head for a few days and any help is appreciated.

Here is my .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h> 

@interface faq2 : UITableViewController 
{
    NSArray *faqList;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *faqList;
-(IBAction)playMovie;
@end
```

Here is my .m

```
-(IBAction)playMovie 
{  
    NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"WhatFinalTake" ofType:@"mp4"];  
    NSURL    *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];  
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];  

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self  
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlaybackComplete:)  
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification  
                                               object:moviePlayerController];  

    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];  
    moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;  
    [moviePlayerController play];   
}

- (void)moviePlaybackComplete:(NSNotification *)notification  
{  
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [notification object];  
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self  
                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification  
                                                  object:moviePlayerController];  

    [moviePlayerController.view removeFromSuperview];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    self.faqList = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                    @"Play Movie",
                    @"Option 1", nil];

    self.title = @"Frequently Asked Questions";
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    self.faqList = nil;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [faqList count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    // Configure the cell.
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.faqList objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]];
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        [self playMovie];
    }
    else if (indexPath.row == 1)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Option 1" message:@"Option 1" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

I am pretty sure I added the framework proplerly, but JIK here is the screenshot.
[image]

Comment: Any error messages in your log?

Comment: is your video about 20 seconds as well? It's likely that the black screen is actually your video,

Comment: I don't know how to check my log and no, my video is about 2 minutes. How do I check my log for errors?

Comment: To check your log you would run your app in the emulator and usually the log will show up at the bottom of your XCode interface.  If it doesn't you can click the middle button of the "View" group at top right on the toolbar.  Or SHift-Command-Y should get it for you to bring up the "Debug Area"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested your code and found that your `filePath` string is `nil`. Try this :

```
NSString *filepath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"WhatFinalTake" ofType:@"mp4"]];  
NSLog(@"%@",filepath);
NSURL    *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];
```

Comment: Hmm. I am new to Xcode. I selected my target and "add files ..." The video file is right above my .m file on the left side of the screen. Is there a specific folder I should put it in? It sounds like the movie is not being found by the code.

Comment: I believe filePath would be nil unless the file exists in your project.

Comment: So I rebuilt the app and deselected "Use Automatic Reference Counting" and the video started playing. Thanks for the hint about logging. It keyed me in on finding out why the player wasn't there when it was needed. I guess "ARC" isn't as smart as I would like.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added your "WhatFinalTake.mp4" file to your project?

I found the following helpful in playing videos, you can call this from your tableView:

http://iosdevelopertips.com/video/getting-mpmovieplayercontroller-to-cooperate-with-ios4-3-2-ipad-and-earlier-versions-of-iphone-sdk.html

I find it is useful to register for notifications LoadStateChanged or PreloadDidFinish (depending on iOS version) and do the actual play from there to be sure the video is prepped.  You can find how to do this from the above link.  Since he has done it all for you I recommend simply using the code provided.